# Shift pandas dataframe down in a cyclical manner

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

If we have the following data:

```
X = pd.DataFrame({"t":[1,2,3,4,5],"A":[34,12,78,84,26], "B":[54,87,35,25,82], "C":[56,78,0,14,13], "D":[0,23,72,56,14], "E":[78,12,31,0,34]})
X

    A   B   C   D   E  t
0  34  54  56   0  78  1
1  12  87  78  23  12  2
2  78  35   0  72  31  3
3  84  25  14  56   0  4
4  26  82  13  14  34  5
```

How can I shift the data in a cyclical fashion so that the next step is:

```
    A   B   C   D   E  t
4  26  82  13  14  34  5 
0  34  54  56   0  78  1
1  12  87  78  23  12  2
2  78  35   0  72  31  3
3  84  25  14  56   0  4
```

And then:

```
    A   B   C   D   E  t
3  84  25  14  56   0  4
4  26  82  13  14  34  5 
0  34  54  56   0  78  1
1  12  87  78  23  12  2
2  78  35   0  72  31  3
```

etc.

This should also shift the index values with the row.

I know of pandas X.shift(), but it wasn't making the cyclical thing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can combine [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with [`np.roll`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html):

```
X = X.reindex(np.roll(X.index, 1))
```

Another option is to combine [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
shift = 1
X = pd.concat([X.iloc[-shift:], X.iloc[:-shift]])
```

The resulting output:

```
    A   B   C   D   E  t
4  26  82  13  14  34  5
0  34  54  56   0  78  1
1  12  87  78  23  12  2
2  78  35   0  72  31  3
3  84  25  14  56   0  4
```

**Timings**

Using the following setup to produce a larger DataFrame and functions for timing:

```
df = pd.concat([X]*10**5, ignore_index=True)

def root1(df, shift):
    return df.reindex(np.roll(df.index, shift))

def root2(df, shift):
    return pd.concat([df.iloc[-shift:], df.iloc[:-shift]])

def ed_chum(df, num):
    return pd.DataFrame(np.roll(df, num, axis=0), np.roll(df.index, num), columns=df.columns)

def divakar1(df, shift):
    return df.iloc[np.roll(np.arange(df.shape[0]), shift)]

def divakar2(df, shift):
    idx = np.mod(np.arange(df.shape[0])-1,df.shape[0])
    for _ in range(shift):
        df = df.iloc[idx]
    return df
```

I get the following timings:

```
%timeit root1(df.copy(), 25)
10 loops, best of 3: 61.3 ms per loop

%timeit root2(df.copy(), 25)
10 loops, best of 3: 26.4 ms per loop

%timeit ed_chum(df.copy(), 25)
10 loops, best of 3: 28.3 ms per loop

%timeit divakar1(df.copy(), 25)
10 loops, best of 3: 177 ms per loop

%timeit divakar2(df.copy(), 25)
1 loop, best of 3: 4.18 s per loop
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`np.roll`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html) in a custom func:

```
In [83]:
def roll(df, num):
    return pd.DataFrame(np.roll(df,num,axis=0), np.roll(df.index, num), columns=df.columns)
​
roll(X,1)

Out[83]:
    A   B   C   D   E  t
4  26  82  13  14  34  5
0  34  54  56   0  78  1
1  12  87  78  23  12  2
2  78  35   0  72  31  3
3  84  25  14  56   0  4

In [84]:
roll(X,2)

Out[84]:
    A   B   C   D   E  t
3  84  25  14  56   0  4
4  26  82  13  14  34  5
0  34  54  56   0  78  1
1  12  87  78  23  12  2
2  78  35   0  72  31  3
```

Here we return a df using the rolled df array, with the index rolled also

Answer (score 2):

You can use `numpy.roll` :

```
import numpy as np

nb_iterations = 3 # number of steps you want
for i in range(nb_iterations):
    for col in X.columns :
        df[col] = numpy.roll(df[col], 1)
```

Which is equivalent to :

```
for col in X.columns :
        df[col] = numpy.roll(df[col], nb_iterations)
```

[Here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html) is a link to the documentation of this useful function.

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be creating such an *shifted-down* indexing array once and re-using it over and over to index into rows with [.iloc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html), like so -

```
idx = np.mod(np.arange(X.shape[0])-1,X.shape[0])
X = X.iloc[idx]
```

Another way to create `idx` would be with `np.roll` : `np.roll(np.arange(X.shape[0]),1)`.

Sample run -

```
In [113]: X   # Starting version
Out[113]: 
    A   B   C   D   E  t
0  34  54  56   0  78  1
1  12  87  78  23  12  2
2  78  35   0  72  31  3
3  84  25  14  56   0  4
4  26  82  13  14  34  5

In [114]: idx = np.mod(np.arange(X.shape[0])-1,X.shape[0]) # Creating once       

In [115]: X = X.iloc[idx] # Using idx

In [116]: X
Out[116]: 
    A   B   C   D   E  t
4  26  82  13  14  34  5
0  34  54  56   0  78  1
1  12  87  78  23  12  2
2  78  35   0  72  31  3
3  84  25  14  56   0  4

In [117]: X = X.iloc[idx] # Re-using idx

In [118]: X
Out[118]: 
    A   B   C   D   E  t
3  84  25  14  56   0  4
4  26  82  13  14  34  5
0  34  54  56   0  78  1
1  12  87  78  23  12  2
2  78  35   0  72  31  3   ## and so on
```