# Addin a new row and keeping index python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I move the result one row down so therefore it will go until the index 2017-11-06 ?
I would like to add 0s to the first row in 2017-10-22

here is my date frame

```
produktname  NEG_00_04  NEG_04_08  NEG_08_12  NEG_12_16  NEG_16_20  NEG_20_24  \
datum_von                                                                       
2017-10-22       10.46       9.73       1.85       6.18       1.32       0.68   
2017-10-23        8.13       7.39       0.61       0.89       0.51       0.54   
2017-10-24        6.11       5.68       0.46       0.84       0.36       0.36   
2017-10-25        4.95       4.40       0.28       0.52       0.21       0.24   
2017-10-26        4.59       4.02       0.24       0.48       0.16       0.20   
2017-10-27       18.01      23.32      12.25      37.96      22.66      54.65   
2017-10-28      138.91     140.96      81.27      41.60      13.17      40.82   
2017-10-29      142.94     152.55      91.93      78.32      31.26      11.87   
2017-10-30       16.54      15.15       1.49       2.09       1.89       3.84   
2017-10-31       12.95      10.86       1.92       2.07       1.86       3.04   
2017-11-01        9.87       9.12       1.23       1.60       1.12       1.60   
2017-11-02        6.79       6.22       0.63       0.88       0.64       0.96   
2017-11-03        3.56       3.45       1.11       1.53       1.24       1.46   
2017-11-04       11.86       9.10       0.93       1.64       1.76       1.69   
2017-11-05         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
```

Comment: `df.shift().fillna(0)`?

Comment: no, I tried it but it will keep the numbers of the rows and I want to add a new row until day 2017-11-06 and move one line down everything and then fill the first row with 0´s @coldspeed

Answer (score 1):

Use [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html):

```
df = df.shift(1, freq='1D')
print (df)
            NEG_00_04  NEG_04_08  NEG_08_12  NEG_12_16  NEG_16_20  NEG_20_24
datum_von                                                                   
2017-10-23      10.46       9.73       1.85       6.18       1.32       0.68
2017-10-24       8.13       7.39       0.61       0.89       0.51       0.54
2017-10-25       6.11       5.68       0.46       0.84       0.36       0.36
2017-10-26       4.95       4.40       0.28       0.52       0.21       0.24
2017-10-27       4.59       4.02       0.24       0.48       0.16       0.20
2017-10-28      18.01      23.32      12.25      37.96      22.66      54.65
2017-10-29     138.91     140.96      81.27      41.60      13.17      40.82
2017-10-30     142.94     152.55      91.93      78.32      31.26      11.87
2017-10-31      16.54      15.15       1.49       2.09       1.89       3.84
2017-11-01      12.95      10.86       1.92       2.07       1.86       3.04
2017-11-02       9.87       9.12       1.23       1.60       1.12       1.60
2017-11-03       6.79       6.22       0.63       0.88       0.64       0.96
2017-11-04       3.56       3.45       1.11       1.53       1.24       1.46
2017-11-05      11.86       9.10       0.93       1.64       1.76       1.69
2017-11-06        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
```

And if need remove last row:

```
df = df.shift(1, freq='1D').iloc[:-1]
print (df)
            NEG_00_04  NEG_04_08  NEG_08_12  NEG_12_16  NEG_16_20  NEG_20_24
datum_von                                                                   
2017-10-23      10.46       9.73       1.85       6.18       1.32       0.68
2017-10-24       8.13       7.39       0.61       0.89       0.51       0.54
2017-10-25       6.11       5.68       0.46       0.84       0.36       0.36
2017-10-26       4.95       4.40       0.28       0.52       0.21       0.24
2017-10-27       4.59       4.02       0.24       0.48       0.16       0.20
2017-10-28      18.01      23.32      12.25      37.96      22.66      54.65
2017-10-29     138.91     140.96      81.27      41.60      13.17      40.82
2017-10-30     142.94     152.55      91.93      78.32      31.26      11.87
2017-10-31      16.54      15.15       1.49       2.09       1.89       3.84
2017-11-01      12.95      10.86       1.92       2.07       1.86       3.04
2017-11-02       9.87       9.12       1.23       1.60       1.12       1.60
2017-11-03       6.79       6.22       0.63       0.88       0.64       0.96
2017-11-04       3.56       3.45       1.11       1.53       1.24       1.46
2017-11-05      11.86       9.10       0.93       1.64       1.76       1.69
```

EDIT by coldspeed suggestion:

```
df = df.shift(1, freq='1D').shift().fillna(0)
print (df)
            NEG_00_04  NEG_04_08  NEG_08_12  NEG_12_16  NEG_16_20  NEG_20_24
datum_von                                                                   
2017-10-23       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00
2017-10-24      10.46       9.73       1.85       6.18       1.32       0.68
2017-10-25       8.13       7.39       0.61       0.89       0.51       0.54
2017-10-26       6.11       5.68       0.46       0.84       0.36       0.36
2017-10-27       4.95       4.40       0.28       0.52       0.21       0.24
2017-10-28       4.59       4.02       0.24       0.48       0.16       0.20
2017-10-29      18.01      23.32      12.25      37.96      22.66      54.65
2017-10-30     138.91     140.96      81.27      41.60      13.17      40.82
2017-10-31     142.94     152.55      91.93      78.32      31.26      11.87
2017-11-01      16.54      15.15       1.49       2.09       1.89       3.84
2017-11-02      12.95      10.86       1.92       2.07       1.86       3.04
2017-11-03       9.87       9.12       1.23       1.60       1.12       1.60
2017-11-04       6.79       6.22       0.63       0.88       0.64       0.96
2017-11-05       3.56       3.45       1.11       1.53       1.24       1.46
2017-11-06      11.86       9.10       0.93       1.64       1.76       1.69
```

Comment: I guess this gives what OP wants - to shift everything by one day: `df.shift(1, freq='1D').shift().fillna(0)`

Comment: NotImplementedError: Not supported for type Index error with the first command @jezrael

Comment: Is index datetime index? `df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)`

Answer (score 0):

I think it's possibly duplicated to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41044817/1278112).
The core code is `df = df.reindex(np.roll(train1.index, 1))`.
So it would be compliance to other indexes which is not a timestamp.
Notice the reindex part.Actually, indexes are immutable so you won't find any of the inplace set operations.
When you want change index is better to use `reindex()`.

```
train1.head()
0   26161   8   26  5   12  6203267.0   7028569.0   36897923.0  25.0    2.912361    2095591
1   225339  8   16  2   18  9444188.0   5706549.0   54998912.0  89.0    0.695894    958323
2   289840  8   26  5   14  29576775.0  20370976.0  7028833.0   30.0    -0.678827   350865
3   440084  8   19  5   20  7028696.0   6203430.0   7028695.0   80.0    -1.865368   3023891
4   445565  8   15  1   11  3239152.0   50914567.0  6203481.0   66.0    -1.675962   235089

df = train1.copy()
df = df.reindex(np.roll(train1.index, 1))
df.head()
4923    63890702    8   24  3   12  7028743.0   24539379.0  52864823.0  62.0    -1.974894   235089
0   26161   8   26  5   12  6203267.0   7028569.0   36897923.0  25.0    2.912361    2095591
1   225339  8   16  2   18  9444188.0   5706549.0   54998912.0  89.0    0.695894    958323
2   289840  8   26  5   14  29576775.0  20370976.0  7028833.0   30.0    -0.678827   350865
3   440084  8   19  5   20  7028696.0   6203430.0   7028695.0   80.0    -1.865368   3023891
```